# Spritekit performance with WAV audio files

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, audio, sprite-kit

In my Spritekit game I currently have a dozen or so sound effects (which I plan on adding several more to) and a few background music loops. They are all currently WAV files. I'm wondering if I will see any performance boost by converting the audio to mp3 (or some other compressed audio type). Obviously this will reduce the app's overall file size, which is great, but I'm wondering if the smaller file sizes will add any performance benefits or if audio file size is irrelevant in iPad/Sprietkit performance. Additionally I'm worried that converting the music loops to mp3 will cause them to not loop perfectly, since mp3's have header meta data at the beginning of the tracks that add a small gap of silence. Thanks!

Comment: mp3 is compressed. The audio is decompressed in memory before being played. Your filesize will be smaller and will load quicker, but once it's decompressed (before playing) your memory footprint will be the same as a uncompressed format. Decompression has a performance cost as you are decompressing before playing - thus the pause. The larger the file, the more pronounced the pause. Most use uncompressed for shorter sounds and compressed for music. Apple docs has "Best Practices" -https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/audiovideo/conceptual/multimediapg/usingaudio/usingaudio.html

Comment: moreover only one mp3 can be decoded on hardware, any additional takes up cpu time to decode

Comment: mp3 = long running audio, wav/caf = short sound effects, to conserve memory reduce sampling rate

Comment: Thanks for the replies. This is great. I read through the whole multi media programming guide. I assume that 1 MP3 can be decoded with hardware for the lifetime of the app? Or is it one at a time? Ideally the background music will play immediately and loop seamlessly, so it sounds like mp3s are out as looping mp3s can result in a gap between loops due to headers. My game loop is around 30 seconds and the home screen and score board music loops are really short like 10 seconds. I'm going to convert everything to caf and see if there is any difference in memory usage compared to waves.

Comment: My testing shows that WAV, CAF, vs MP3s for background music and WAV vs CAF for sound effects all use the same amount of memory in XCode's Debug Session. I can tell no difference at all in audio performance. I was also surprised to find the the MP3s loop just fine. The MP3s definitely don't sound as good as the other 2. I'm going to continue with WAVs until I need to reduce the app's size (is only 72 MB). At which point I'll likely go with CAF. My game music WAV is 28 MB where the CAF file is only 9.3 MB. I don't like how the MP3s sound. Both the CAF & MP3's are quieter than the WAVs.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix performance problems with preload.

```
SKAction *soundAction;

- (void)didMoveToView: (SKView *) yourView
{
    _soundAction = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"yourSoundFile" waitForCompletion:NO];
}

[self runAction:_soundAction];//Play your sound where you want.
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll add that. But that doesn't quite answer my question. I guess I could re-phrase it. Will smaller audio files use less memory? Is it recommended to use mp3s in games over wav files?

Comment: Thanks Valar! Once I added too many sound effects this became necessary.